# How to update javascript variable after ajax call back

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to update javascript variable after ajax call back

```
var x =1;

$(document).on('click','.classname',function(){
console.log(x);
});

$.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:tmplUri+'/ajax/test.php',
        cache:false,
        async:false,
        data:{journey:'yes'},
        success: function(data)
        {
          x = data;
         }
});
```

after ajax call i need to update the variable on that page

Please give any suggestion for this issue

Comment: Whats the issue? Your code should do that

Comment: variable ' x' not updated after ajax call

Comment: maybe the ajax failed?are you sure it is a success also dont use ASYNC FALSE

Comment: @Pekka ajax is working

Comment: Is the success method is called ? Try by adding the "debugger" keyword in the method, and launch the page with the debugger tool (F12).

Comment: async false is a no go for sure...

Comment: Your issue lloks like a scope one but anyway this isn't the way you should hanlde result from ajax request, using a global var. See for better idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Try this with your php URL: http://jsfiddle.net/qq3zg18z/ Your code looks good!

Answer (score 2):

for this you need a globle variable, just Call a another function to reset you variable after ajax call

```
  var x // make it globle


    $(document).on('click','.classname',function(){
    console.log(x);
    });

    function resetx(){
     x =1;
    }


    $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:tmplUri+'/ajax/test.php',
            cache:false,
            async:false,
            data:{journey:'yes'},
            success: function(data)
            {
              x = data;
             }
    });


calling hierarchy

ajaxcall 
resetx

than check you variable it will give you 1
```

here the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q8Qdb/401/)

Comment: In example it looks global too!

Comment: i know wait i am creating fiddle

Comment: @RayonDabre Ya but i guess it isn't. Opening post missing some context for sure